# Finding all rows with unique combination of two columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, duplicates, aggregate

I have this table `messages`;

```
sender_id    recipient_id
1            2
1            3
1            3
2            1
3            1
2            3
```

I wish to select rows such that:

1. Either `sender_id` or `receiver_id` = `current_user.id`.
2. The other field should be unique.

I.e. I want to select unique from table where `sender_id = 2` or `recipient_id = 2` and I need this result:

```
sender_id    recipient_id
2            1
2            3
```

How to do it?
Why? Because I wish to build a facebook-like inbox in which sent and received messages are aggregated, and this query is the bottleneck so far.

I am using rails 3.2 and Postgres 9.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT sender_id AS user_id, recipient_id AS other_user_id
FROM   messages
WHERE  sender_id = $current_user_id

UNION
SELECT recipient_id, sender_id
FROM   messages
WHERE  recipient_id = $current_user_id
-- ORDER BY 1, 2  -- optional
```

`UNION` (not `UNION ALL`) removes duplicates from the result making`DISTINCT` unnecessary. 
You might want to add `ORDER BY` at the end for sorted output.

Assuming a big table with relatively few qualifying rows, two btree indexes typically deliver best performance. One with leading or only `sender_id`, another one with leading or only `recipient_id`.

A single [**multicolumn index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) on `(sender_id, receiver_id)` or vice versa also works, but typically slower. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Comment: @Erwin how do I order these results to get the most recent first? The table also has an id column, and a created_at column both of which can be used for sorting... but how?

Comment: @ZuhaibAli: First you would have to define *which* value to pick for each group of duplicates. The smallest `id` / `created_at` per group? I suggest you write a new question with the detailed requirements. You can always refer to this one for context.

Comment: Note that I replaced my original answer with a better one.

Answer (score 3):

With ANSI SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sender_id, reciepient_id
FROM messages
WHERE (sender_id = current_user.id or reciepient_id = current_user.id)
```

Comment: If you have independent indexes on both `sender_id` and `receiver_id` (*not* a composite index on both together), PostgreSQL should use a bitmap index scan to find matching rows, too.

Comment: This fails to remove duplicates.

Comment: Yes, this won't remove (1,2) vs (2,1) duplicates