# Get list of user who are involved in conversation

Tags: sql, postgresql

My "users" table is like this

```
id   name 
1    UserA
2    UserB
3    UserC
4    UserD
```

And my "chats" table is like this

```
id   text        sentBy    sentTo    created 
1    Hi UserB    1         2         2019-01-11
2    Hi          2         1         2019-01-12
3    Hi UserB    3         2         2019-01-13
4    Hello UserC 2         3         2019-01-14
5    Hello       3         2         2019-01-15
6    What u do   2         1         2019-01-16
7    Nothing     1         2         2019-01-17
8    Okay        2         1         2019-01-18
8    Hi UserA    3         1         2019-01-19
```

I want to show user list who is involved in a conversation with logged in user based on the last msg.
Like if UserA logged in the system then the list should be like

```
userId    userName      text           created
3         UserC         Hi UserA       2019-01-19
2         UserB         Okay           2019-01-19
```

I tried by using a join query and group by but not succeed.
I am using PostgreSQL with koa js.

Comment: Essential details are missing: Postgres version (`SELECT version();`, table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement). And it looks like you have an error in the result: `2019-01-19` <> `2019-01-18`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `DISTINCT ON` to filter out all apart from the most recent record for each involved in the conversation.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON( involved) involved AS userid, 
                              u.NAME   AS username, 
                              text, 
                              created 
FROM   (SELECT c.*, 
               CASE sentby 
                 WHEN 1 THEN sentto 
                 ELSE sentby 
               END AS involved 
        FROM   chats c 
        WHERE  c.sentby = 1 
                OR c.sentto = 1) s 
       JOIN users u 
         ON s.involved = u.id 
ORDER  BY involved, 
          created DESC
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8daf97027373eeb7051f3ea1a87c5fd8)

If you want a generic case, you may convert this to a SQL type Postgres function and pass `userid` as an argument and use it in place of 1.

Answer (score 1):

To get a complete list of users involved in the last conversation of the `$current_user`, with the last message (sent or received) and its date (`created`):

```
WITH u1 AS (SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = $current_user)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (userId) *
FROM  (
   SELECT u.id AS userId, u.name AS userName, c.text, c.created  -- received
   FROM   u1
   JOIN   chats c ON c.sentBy = u1.id
   JOIN   users u ON u.id = c.sentTo

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT u.id, u.name, c.text, c.created -- sent
   FROM   u1
   JOIN   chats c ON c.sentTo = u1.id
   JOIN   users u ON u.id = c.sentBy
   ) sub
ORDER  BY userId, created DESC;
```

I separated into two UNIONed SELECTs, to make the most of *two* separate indexes on `chats` - one with leading `sentTo`, one with leading `sentBy`. Just updated a closely related answer yesterday:

- [Finding all rows with unique combination of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729000/finding-all-rows-with-unique-combination-of-two-columns/22730964#comment96625076_22730964)

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Might be optimized in various ways, depending on undisclosed information.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This way is also working. I had tried the same way by using groupBy but PostgreSQL is throwing an error until is add all select field in groupBy.

Comment: @ProCylon: `GROUP BY` is no good for the purpose. Follow the link I provided for `DISTNCT ON` for a detailed explanation.